# Valgrind outputs unrelated to program error messages in MacOS High Sierra

Tags: valgrind, macos-high-sierra

I've been trying Valgrind out with the following program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#define BUF_SIZE 1000

int main() {
  char *path = new char[BUF_SIZE]

  return 0;
}
```

Evidently the program has a memory leak, but when I test Valgrind I get a lot of unrelated leak errors, in addition to the actual leak.

I installed Valgrind using the instructions I found in: https://www.gungorbudak.com/blog/2018/04/28/how-to-install-valgrind-on-macos-high-sierra/

I even tried the use --suppressions with darwin*.supp (from the Git Repository https://sourceware.org/git/?p=valgrind.git)

Any suggestions or advice will be welcome.

```
ARIAS-CSC-MBP:cpp arias$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./test
==72896== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==72896== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==72896== Using Valgrind-3.14.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==72896== Command: ./test
==72896==
==72896==
==72896== HEAP SUMMARY:
==72896==     in use at exit: 19,411 bytes in 167 blocks
==72896==   total heap usage: 188 allocs, 21 frees, 27,859 bytes allocated
==72896==
==72896== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 27 of 47
==72896==    at 0x1000ACC32: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-5f900ed/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==72896==    by 0x10075ABA4: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x10075AC5A: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100759363: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100757AC4: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x10076A7DA: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100007C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==    by 0x100007E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==    by 0x10022271D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100757075: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x1001ACB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x1001ACB1B: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==72896==
==72896== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 28 of 47
==72896==    at 0x1000ACC32: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-5f900ed/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==72896==    by 0x10075ABA4: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x10075AC72: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x10075AC5A: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100759363: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100757AC4: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x10076A7DA: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100007C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==    by 0x100007E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==    by 0x10022271D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100757075: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x1001ACB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==72896==
==72896== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 29 of 47
==72896==    at 0x1000ACC32: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-5f900ed/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==72896==    by 0x1007577E2: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x10076A7DA: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100007C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==    by 0x100007E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==    by 0x10022271D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100757075: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x1001ACB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x1001ACB1B: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x1000BB9C2: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100019AC5: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==    by 0x100019CF5: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==
==72896== 1,000 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 39 of 47
==72896==    at 0x1000ACC32: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-5f900ed/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==72896==    by 0x100000EF1: main (anothertest.cpp:8)
==72896==
==72896== 1,792 bytes in 28 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 44 of 47
==72896==    at 0x1000ACC32: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-5f900ed/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==72896==    by 0x10075ABA4: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x10075AC72: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100759363: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100757AC4: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x10076A7DA: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100007C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==    by 0x100007E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==72896==    by 0x10022271D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x100757075: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x1001ACB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==72896==    by 0x1001ACB1B: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==72896==
==72896== LEAK SUMMARY:
==72896==    definitely lost: 2,920 bytes in 31 blocks
==72896==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==72896==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==72896==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 6 blocks
==72896==         suppressed: 16,219 bytes in 127 blocks
==72896== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==72896== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==72896==
==72896== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==72896== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 16 from 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is currently pre-release software for macOS High Sierra. As Valgrind needs to hook at a low level into the macOS kernel (mach) it needs continual tweaking upon each major new release of macOS.

At present, that means even using development Git versions of Valgrind, there will be false-positive errors (or at least memory errors which you can do nothing about) in library code which runs within the process space of your small test executable.

Future development releases of Valgrind may addresses these system errors. You can comfortably ignore them if not reporting problems in your own code.